# Issues getting databinding working with Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

I use the MVVM Light framework, but I have issues getting any reactions on properties I have binded to

I have a an object BuyoutRule

```
public class BuyoutRule : ViewModelBase
{
   /*
   More private fields and properties
   */
    public int MaximumPrice
    {
        get { return _maximumPrice; }
        set
        {
            _maximumPrice = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MaximumPrice);
        }
    }

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return _enabled; }
        set
        {
            _enabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Enabled);
        }
    }
```

These objects are in an ObservableCollection in this class

```
public class BuyoutCheapModuleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

private ObservableCollection<BuyoutRule> _buyoutRules;
public ObservableCollection<BuyoutRule> BuyoutRules
    {
        get { return _buyoutRules; }
        set
        {
            _buyoutRules = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => BuyoutRules);
        }
    }
public BuyoutCheapModuleViewModel(IBuyoutRuleQuery buyoutRuleQuery)
      {
            BuyoutRules = new ObservableCollection<BuyoutRule>();
      }
}
```

Then I have the View that has the previous class as Datacontext

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BuyoutRules, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBuyoutRule, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Last Name" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Player.LastName}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rating" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Player.Rating}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Last Name" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Player.Position}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mininum Buyout" IsReadOnly="False" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <xctk:IntegerUpDown Increment="1000"
                                                    Value="{Binding MinimumBuyoutPrice, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                    Minimum="0"
                                                    FormatString="N0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Maximum Buyout">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <xctk:IntegerUpDown Increment="1000"
                                                    Value="{Binding MaximumPrice, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                    Minimum="0"
                                                    FormatString="N0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Enabled">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveSelectedCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding QuickbuyEnabled}">Enable quickbuy</CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

But if I put breakpoints in Setter in either MaximumPrice or Enabled and change the values in my UI nothing happens, I can not get the setters to be triggered, the only time they are triggerd is when the view is created and the initial loaded data is filled in

Comment: Set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on your bindings and see if that helps

Comment: That worked, cant mark you comment as answer though, just thought I had tried it, but must have missed something before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default UpdateSourceTrigger for a datagrid cell is `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`, but you just use a `CellTemplate` which means this never gets hit. Changing it to `PropertyChanged` will allow you to TwoWay bind.